# utility to manipulate java.util.logging config using command-line system properties

Tags: java, logging

This is intended for temporary ad-hoc changes to logging config, for example when debugging etc. Also included are functions to easily manipulate config from a code (for example at the beginning of a given program's `main` method or from `@BeforeClass` JUnit method).
I'm looking mainly for reviews of the API design (whether something can be changed to be more convenient or more intuitive to use).
This class is a part of a small [java.util.logging utility lib](https://github.com/morgwai/jul-utils) that I've created.

```java
// Copyright (c) Piotr Morgwai Kotarbinski, Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0
package pl.morgwai.base.jul;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.BiFunction;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.LogManager;



/**
 * Utilities to manipulate {@code java.util.logging} config, among others allows to override log
 * levels with system properties in existing java apps without rebuilding: see
 * {@link #overrideLogLevelsWithSystemProperties(String...)} and {@link #JulConfigurator()}.
 */
public class JulConfigurator {



    /**
     * Overrides {@link Level}s of {@code java.util.logging} {@link java.util.logging.Logger}s and
     * {@link java.util.logging.Handler}s with values obtained from system properties.
     * Fully-qualified names of {@link java.util.logging.Logger Logger}s and
     * {@link java.util.logging.Handler Handler}s whose {@link Level}s should be overridden, can be
     * provided as {@code loggerAndHandlerNames} arguments and/or comma separated on
     * {@value #OVERRIDE_LEVEL_PROPERTY} system property.
     * <p>
     * Name of the system property containing a new {@link Level} for a given
     * {@link java.util.logging.Logger}/{@link java.util.logging.Handler} is constructed by
     * appending {@value #LEVEL_SUFFIX} to the given
     * {@link java.util.logging.Logger}'s&nbsp;/&nbsp;{@link java.util.logging.Handler}'s
     * fully-qualified name.<br/>
     * If a system property with a new {@link Level} is missing, it is simply ignored.</p>
     * <p>
     * <b>Example:</b><br/>
     * Output all entries from <code>com.example</code> name-space with level <code>FINE</code> or
     * higher to the console. Entries from other name-spaces will be logged only if they have at
     * least level <code>WARNING</code> (unless configured otherwise in the default
     * <code>logging.properties</code> file) :</p>
     * <pre>{@code
     * java -cp ${CLASSPATH}:/path/to/jul-utils.jar \
     *      -Djava.util.logging.config.class=pl.morgwai.base.jul.JulConfigurator \
     *      -Djava.util.logging.overrideLevel=,com.example,java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler \
     *      -D.level=WARNING \
     *      -Dcom.example.level=FINE \
     *      -Djava.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=FINE \
     *      com.example.someproject.MainClass}</pre>
     * <p>
     * (Name of the root {@link java.util.logging.Logger} is an empty string, hence the value of
     * {@value #OVERRIDE_LEVEL_PROPERTY} starts with a comma, so that the first element of the list
     * is an empty string, while {@code -D.level} provides the new {@link Level} for the root
     * {@link java.util.logging.Logger}).</p>
     * <p>
     * Note: overriding can be applied to existing java apps at startup without rebuilding: just add
     * {@code jul-utils.jar} to the command-line class-path and define
     * {@value #JUL_CONFIG_CLASS_PROPERTY} as in the example above.</p>
     */
    public static void overrideLogLevelsWithSystemProperties(String... loggerAndHandlerNames) {
        final var loggerAndHandlerNamesSet = new HashSet<String>();
        Collections.addAll(loggerAndHandlerNamesSet, loggerAndHandlerNames);
        final var namesFromProperty = System.getProperty(OVERRIDE_LEVEL_PROPERTY);
        if (namesFromProperty != null) {
            Collections.addAll(loggerAndHandlerNamesSet, namesFromProperty.split(","));
        }
        if (loggerAndHandlerNamesSet.isEmpty()) return;
        overrideLogLevelsWithSystemProperties(loggerAndHandlerNamesSet);
    }

    static void overrideLogLevelsWithSystemProperties(Set<String> loggerAndHandlerNames) {
        final var newLogLevels = new Properties();  // loggerName.level -> newLevel
        int characterCount = 30;  // first line date comment character length
        for (final var loggerOrHandlerName: loggerAndHandlerNames) {
            // read a system property with the new level and put it into newLogLevels
            final var newLevelPropertyName = loggerOrHandlerName + LEVEL_SUFFIX;
            final var newLevel = System.getProperty(newLevelPropertyName);
            if (newLevel == null) continue;
            newLogLevels.put(newLevelPropertyName, newLevel);
            characterCount += newLevelPropertyName.length();
            characterCount += newLevel.length();
            characterCount += 2;  // '=' and '\n'
        }
        if (newLogLevels.isEmpty()) return;

        logManagerUpdateConfiguration(
            LogManager.getLogManager(),
            newLogLevels,
            characterCount * 2,  // *2 is for UTF characters and \ escapes
            addOrReplaceMapper
        );
    }



    /**
     * Reads logging config normally and then calls
     * {@link #overrideLogLevelsWithSystemProperties(String...)}.
     * For use with {@value #JUL_CONFIG_CLASS_PROPERTY} system property: when this property is set
     * to the {@link Class#getName() fully-qualified name} of this class, then {@link LogManager}
     * will call this constructor instead of reading its configuration the normal way.
     * <p>
     * Note: overriding can be applied to existing java apps without rebuilding: just add
     * {@code jul-utils.jar} to command-line class-path. See the example in
     * {@link #overrideLogLevelsWithSystemProperties(String...)} documentation.</p>
     * @see LogManager
     */
    public JulConfigurator() throws IOException {
        final var julConfigClassPropertyBackup = System.getProperty(JUL_CONFIG_CLASS_PROPERTY);
        System.clearProperty(JUL_CONFIG_CLASS_PROPERTY);
        LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration();
        overrideLogLevelsWithSystemProperties();
        System.setProperty(JUL_CONFIG_CLASS_PROPERTY, julConfigClassPropertyBackup);
    }



    /**
     * Name of the system property that can contain comma separated,
     * {@link Class#getName() fully-qualified names} of {@link java.util.logging.Logger}s and
     * {@link java.util.logging.Handler}s whose {@link java.util.logging.Level}s will be overridden
     * by {@link #overrideLogLevelsWithSystemProperties(String...)}.
     */
    public static final String OVERRIDE_LEVEL_PROPERTY = "java.util.logging.overrideLevel";
    /** {@value #LEVEL_SUFFIX} */
    public static final String LEVEL_SUFFIX = ".level";
    /** {@value #JUL_CONFIG_CLASS_PROPERTY} */
    public static final String JUL_CONFIG_CLASS_PROPERTY = "java.util.logging.config.class";
    static final Function<String, BiFunction<String,String,String>> addOrReplaceMapper =
            (key) -> (oldVal, newVal) -> newVal != null ? newVal : oldVal;



    /**
     * Similar to {@link LogManager#updateConfiguration(InputStream, Function)}, but takes a
     * {@link Properties} argument instead of an {@link InputStream}.
     * This is somewhat a low-level method: in most situations
     * {@link #addOrReplaceLoggingConfigProperties(Properties)} or
     * {@link #addOrReplaceLoggingConfigProperties(Map)} will be more convenient.
     * @param estimatedLoggingConfigUpdatesByteSize estimated size of loggingConfigUpdates in bytes.
     *     It will be passed to {@link ByteArrayOutputStream#ByteArrayOutputStream(int)}.
     */
    public static void logManagerUpdateConfiguration(
        LogManager logManager,
        Properties loggingConfigUpdates,
        int estimatedLoggingConfigUpdatesByteSize,
        Function<String, BiFunction<String,String,String>> mapper
    ) {
        try {
            final var outputBytes =
                    new NoCopyByteArrayOutputStream(estimatedLoggingConfigUpdatesByteSize);
            try (outputBytes) { loggingConfigUpdates.store(outputBytes, null); }
            try (
                final var inputBytes =
                        new ByteArrayInputStream(outputBytes.getBuffer(), 0, outputBytes.size())
            ) {
                logManager.updateConfiguration(inputBytes, mapper);
            }
        } catch (IOException neverHappens) {  // byte array streams don't throw
            throw new RuntimeException(neverHappens);
        }
    }

    static class NoCopyByteArrayOutputStream extends ByteArrayOutputStream {
        public byte[] getBuffer() { return buf; }
        public NoCopyByteArrayOutputStream(int initialSize) { super(initialSize); }
    }



    /**
     * Adds to or replaces logging config properties with entries from {@code loggingConfigUpdates}.
     */
    public static void addOrReplaceLoggingConfigProperties(Properties loggingConfigUpdates) {
        logManagerUpdateConfiguration(
            LogManager.getLogManager(),
            loggingConfigUpdates,
            80 * loggingConfigUpdates.size(),  // in most cases more efficient than calculating
            addOrReplaceMapper
        );
    }



    /**
     * Variant of {@link #addOrReplaceLoggingConfigProperties(Properties)} that takes a {@link Map}
     * as an argument.
     * This allows to use {@link Map#of(Object, Object) Map.of(...)} function family inline, for
     * example:
     * <pre>{@code
     * addOrReplaceLoggingConfigProperties(Map.of(
     *     ".level", "FINE",
     *     "java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level", "FINEST",
     *     "com.example.level", "FINEST",
     *     "com.thirdparty.level", "WARNING"
     * ));}</pre>
     */
    public static void addOrReplaceLoggingConfigProperties(Map<String, String> loggingConfigUpdates)
    {
        final var propertiesUpdates = new Properties(loggingConfigUpdates.size());
        propertiesUpdates.putAll(loggingConfigUpdates);
        addOrReplaceLoggingConfigProperties(propertiesUpdates);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javadocs may be found
[here](https://javadoc.io/doc/pl.morgwai.base/jul-utils/latest/pl/morgwai/base/jul/JulConfigurator.html#overrideLogLevelsWithSystemProperties(java.lang.String...)).

## copyright notice

```
// Copyright (c) Piotr Morgwai Kotarbinski, ...
```

Let's assume you wish to enjoy
[USPTO](https://www.uspto.gov)
copyright protection under U.S. law.
Then elide the `(c)`, as it has no special meaning
(or replace it with `©` if you prefer).
Their [circular](https://www.copyright.gov/circs/circ03.pdf)
explains you are missing one of the three elements of a copyright notice.
Add the year, e.g. `// Copyright 2024 Piotr ...`

## overrideLogLevelsWithSystemProperties

> Name ... is an empty string

Thank you, I found that explanation very helpful.

```
final var loggerAndHandlerNamesSet = ...
```

I'm not crazy about that identifier, nor about the `...Set` suffix.

This local is "the same as" the input String array,
just organized for more efficient access.
So give it a simple local variable name like `names` and be done with it.
No need for "Gimli, son of Glóin, son of Gróin"
when a simple "Gimli" is sufficient among friends.

I *do* like how we finish by calling the private helper `overrideLogLevelsWithSystemProperties()`.
However, the helper has same name, different signature,
yet it performs a **different** task,
as it never calls `System.getProperty()`.
So perhaps we would prefer that these two functions had slightly different names?

In the helper, I similarly would prefer to see `for (name: names) {`

```
            characterCount += 2;  // '=' and '\n'
```

This is a good example of offering the "why" rather than the "how".
I thank you for the explanation.
Similarly for the UTF-16 remark (it seems UTF-32 is not of interest, cool).

## checked exception

```
    public JulConfigurator() throws IOException {
```

Possibly this signature is not convenient for callers?
Consider re-throwing, wrapped in an unchecked RuntimeException.
(I also appreciate the `neverHappens` name.)

We clear, read config, and set.

Suppose that reading failed with an I/O error.
Would it maybe be nicer to read config, *then* clear, and set?
So a thrown exception won't reveal the "cleared" state?

## magic number

```
    80 * loggingConfigUpdates.size(),  // in most cases more efficient than calculating
```

This seems nice enough as-is.

But consider naming that integer,
just so you can give it a Javadoc entry
that warns unusual callers there is room to lose
in rare circumstances.

Comment: Many thanks for the review!  
**file header:** now i will have to `sed` *all* my github repos... you have no idea how much i hate you now ;) Seriously though: many thanks for pointing this!
**loggerAndHandlerNamesSet:** i'll change it to `combinedNames` as it combines names from both the vararg param and the system property.
**private helper not actually using system properties:** you must have missed it ;) [Line 77](https://github.com/morgwai/jul-utils/blob/master/src/main/java/pl/morgwai/base/jul/JulConfigurator.java#L77) reads new log levels from system properties.

Comment: **UTF remark explanation:** actually `Properties.store()` always uses [ISO-8859-1](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Properties.java#L897) and escapes Unicode chars using `\uXXXX` and few other special chars using `\` (see [the source](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Properties.java#L677)). I'll change the comment to be less misleading.

Comment: **checked exception:** this constructor will probably never be called directly by any user-code: it is called by `LogManager` who does not discriminate between checked/unchecked ;)
**exception in clear/read/set:** yeah, that's a bug: i'll put the setting part in a `finally` block. Thanks for catching this! (clearing must happen before `LogManager.readConfiguration()`, otherwise it will again delegate to this constructor and there will be infinite recursion).
**better documenting rough estimates using magic numbers:** great point, i'll do so.
Thank you for so many good advices!

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/morgwai/jul-utils/commit/3d9730596eb508ab2728c798e9b142ce8a7315b3
Thanks again! :)